# change image View ontouch

Tags: imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a database contains name's of images , I display the first image on imageView , I switched between images using ontouch up and down but that not usefull, I want to switch between images by moving finger right or left , any help please???

Answer (score 0):

```
ivSaison.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
    switch (event.getAction())
    {
         // when user first touches the screen we get x and y coordinate
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                          
          {                             
             x1 = event.getX();
             y1 = event.getY();
             break;
           }                         
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:                          
           {
             x2 =event.getX();
             //Si le glissement du doigt de gauche à droite 
             if (x1 < x2)
             {
                ...........................
              }
             //Si le glissement du doigt de droite à gauche
              else                             
              {
                ...........................                   
              }
                ...........................                    
              break;                                           
           }                 
     } return true;
```

} });